# An unhandled exception of type System.AccessViolationException

Tags: arcobjects

I am trying to upgrade a desktop extension from ArcGIS 10.0 to ArcGIS 10.2. I am getting this error:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in GIS.Metadata.dll.
```

Not sure what may be causing this. My Environment: VS2013, ArcGIS 10.2, VB.NET, Windows 7 (64 bit). I have also added code where it’s failing.

```
pGxCatalog = New ESRI.ArcGIS.Catalog.GxCatalog
'// connect to root ... 
pGxCatalog.ConnectFolder(IO.Path.GetPathRoot(pPath))

'// connect to folder via Location property
pGxCatalog.Location = IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(pPath) '
```

**Fails here**

```
pCatObject = pGxCatalog.GetObjectFromFullName(pPath, numFound)
```

IF I set the location manually (say C:) it errors on the above line.